# CSV to Oracle from Pandas (but not using to_sql because that's slow)

Tags: oracle, csv, python-3.x

Can some one tell me the best (fastest) way to send data from a pandas data frame to Oracle? With pandas to_sql, it's depressingly slow due to one insert statement per row.

I tried odo, but cannot get passed a compilation error (construct has no default compilation handler) and documentation is not helping. [Here's a related post of mine with a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804162/csv-to-oracle-via-odo-and-sql-alchemy).

I know there is a sql loader option for Python, but have never run a sub process (does that work in the Jupyter notebook?).

Ultimately, I'm trying to automate loading data from a CSV into Oracle on a monthly basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) python module which can do an insert of a list using the executemany() method. So you can convert your dataframe to a list or just load your csv file as a list and then load it into Oracle.

Comment: That would be great. I just tried that, actually, following this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html  Is the speed comparable to SQL Loader?

Comment: Yes, I would say the speed is comparable. I use it for a lot of different jobs and never have any issues.

Comment: Do I need a list of lists (from the data frame)?

Comment: You just need to make sure that whatever you pass into the executemany() method is of the python type list. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have a column that is formatted as datetime64[ns]. How do I specify this as such in cursor.setinputsizes()? I'll ask a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: yes please post a separate question with some example code and i will try to help you out

Comment: Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869371/cx-oracle-equivalent-of-datetime64ns