# cx_Oracle equivalent of datetime64[ns]

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, cx-oracle

Given the following kind of data in a column of a Pandas data frame (Pandas data type is datetime64[ns]:

```
Contract_EffDt
1974-02-01
```

I want to import this (along with some string and int columns) into Oracle like this:

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
.
.
.
cur.setinputsizes(25,25,255,255,25,25,25,255,255,25,25,cx.DATE,int)
cur=con.cursor()
cur.bindarraysize = 1000
cur.executemany('''insert into Table(Contract_ID,Plan_ID,Org_Type,Plan_Type,Offers_Part_D,SNP_Plan,\
EGHP,Org_Name,Org_Mkt_Name,Plan_Name,Parent_Org,Contract_EffDt,YYYYMM) values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13)''', rows)
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

How can I get cx_Oracle to recognize my datetime column for what it is and insert it accordingly? As you can see, I've tried cx.DATE but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

**Update with more information:**

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd
pwd=pwd
namec='table'
con = cx.Connection("table/"+pwd+"@server")
dfc=pd.read_csv(r'\\...\CPSC_Contract_Info_2016_03.csv',
                encoding='latin-1')
#taken from https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Downloads/2016/March/CPSC-Enrollment-2016-03.zip 
#^contract info file^
rows=dfc.values.tolist()
dfc['Contract_EffDt'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Contract_EffDt'])
dfc['Contract_EffDt'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Contract_EffDt'],format='%YYYY-%mm-%dd')
dfc['Plan_ID']=dfc['Plan_ID'].astype(str)
dfc.dtypes

Contract_ID               object
Plan_ID                   object
Org_Type                  object
Plan_Type                 object
Offers_Part_D             object
SNP_Plan                  object
EGHP                      object
Org_Name                  object
Org_Mkt_Name              object
Plan_Name                 object
Parent_Org                object
Contract_EffDt    datetime64[ns]
YYYYMM                     int64
dtype: object

cur.setinputsizes(25,25,255,255,25,25,25,255,255,25,25,cx.DATETIME,int)
cur=con.cursor()
cur.bindarraysize = 1000
cur.executemany('''insert into table(Contract_ID,Plan_ID,Org_Type,Plan_Type,Offers_Part_D,SNP_Plan,\
EGHP,Org_Name,Org_Mkt_Name,Plan_Name,Parent_Org,Contract_EffDt,YYYYMM) values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,to_date(:12,'yyyy-mm-dd'),:13)''', rows)
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-6696ee05e0f2> in <module>()
      4 cur=con.cursor()
      5 cur.bindarraysize = 1000
----> 6 cur.executemany('''insert into table(Contract_ID,Plan_ID,Org_Type,Plan_Type,Offers_Part_D,SNP_Plan,EGHP,Org_Name,Org_Mkt_Name,Plan_Name,Parent_Org,Contract_EffDt,YYYYMM) values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,to_date(:12,'yyyy-mm-dd'),:13)''', rows)
      7 con.commit()
      8 cur.close()


TypeError: expecting numeric data
```

Comment: try doing a to_date function on your bind variables since oracle is probably just treating it as a string

Comment: why don't you want to use [to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function???

Comment: I tried that, but it's slower than molasses in January.

Comment: try turning the value into a str() or int() on the python side before loading it into oracle.

Comment: Just tried that: dfc['Contract_EffDt']=dfc['Contract_EffDt'].astype(str), used 25 for the input size, and :12 for the bind argument. No dice.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to convert the data frame into a list after converting types to strings. New error, however: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdf' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Pertaining to the Unicode Encode Error above, I converted all fields to utf-8 (i.e. dfc['EGHP']=dfc['EGHP'].str.encode('utf-8')
) and now have: DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "YYYYMM": invalid identifier